# error with RSelenium

Tags: r, selenium, rselenium

after a lot with struggle to get the docker running correctly, i have the following error when trying to use RSelenium:

```
Selenium message:The path to the driver executable must be set by the 
webdriver.gecko.driver system property; for more information, see 
https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver. The latest version can be downloaded 
from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases

 Error:      Summary: UnknownError
 Detail: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
 class: java.lang.IllegalStateException
 Further Details: run errorDetails method
```

The code is just:

```
remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost" 
                      , port = 4444
                      , browserName = "firefox"
                      )

remDr$open()
```

And whe I try to see the page `https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver`, i get error 404. Anyone knows what is this about? Im using windows.

Comment: Did you download geckodriver.exe from Github? This is needed if you want to use the Firefox driver with Selenium.

Comment: I guess not. I just installed docker and selenium. But this happens when I try to navigate using chrome also.

Comment: I've never tried using Chrome drivers for Selenium, but you should try downloading the gecko driver and seeing if that helps.

Comment: Can you help me with that? I know this is ask for much, but with the file I have here, the installation has not been successful.

Comment: What version of selenium/node-firefox docker image are you using?

Comment: 2:53:0, @Barney

Comment: [https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver) does not return a 404. You might want to check your internet connection and your proxy, if you're using one.